# Mod rewrite with query strings after .html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to perform a mod rewriting to my web site. And I used to do this rewriting for quite some time. Of course I am very much upto the task until I met new requirement to create a rewritten URL with query strings after **.html**
Example - http://kypseli/admin/catagory.html?parent_id=1

I have used this this regex.
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+).([html])/?$ index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`

But the query string value (parent_id) not passing. 
This is working with out the **.html** part for perfection. 

 http://kypseli/admin/catagory/?parent_id=1 
But I want it with **.html** part, as I have found lots and lots of same technique usage every where in WWW. here is one example
http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/video_audio/559158.html?genre=46

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all query string elements from the first query to be appended on your rewritten query you need to add the `[QSA]` flag to the rewriteRule, or `[qsappend]` if you prefer long and descriptive tags.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1 [qsappend]
```

Now I do not understand fully what you mean about '.html', but I hope this will be enough.

**EDIT**

your problem is maybe the dot, it should be escaped `\.` and it should be in the optionnal part if it is optionall so :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)/?$ index.php?rt=$1 [qsappend]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)\.html?$ index.php?rt=$1 [qsappend]
```

Or if you want only one rule, this should work (untested)

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/_]+)([\.html|/])?$ index.php?rt=$1 [qsappend]
```

And it's unsure you really need the `?` in your rewriteRule, you may want to apply it even without query strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Yes I can pass all my query strings by adding [qsappend]. But Still I It is not working when I use the ".html" before query string starts.
Ex - This is working `http://kypseli/admin/catagory/?parent_id=1`
But.......
This is not working `http://kypseli/admin/catagory.html?parent_id=1`
Hope you got it this time.

Comment: Thank you man, worked `RewriteRule ^(mypage.m3u8)?$ content.php?id=$1 [qsappend]`